# Nginx docker communication to php container - connection refused

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

New to docker and nginx set up at this level. Having issues getting nginx to talk to php container. Keep getting `502 Bad Gateway`when navigating, with the following errors from docker:

```
web            | 2018/03/21 09:25:40 [error] 6#6: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: web, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.4:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
web            | 172.18.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2018:09:25:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36" "-"
web            | 2018/03/21 09:25:40 [error] 6#6: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: web, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.4:9000", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
web            | 172.18.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2018:09:25:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

My nginx conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    # listen 443 ssl;
    server_name web;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        # see laravel docs On Nginx, the following directive in your site configuration will allow "pretty" URLs:
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;

        fastcgi_param DB_HOST mariadb:33061;
        fastcgi_param DB_DATABASE homestead;
        fastcgi_param DEFAULT_HOME_URL $http_host;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
    }
}
```

and my docker compose yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./nginx/insight.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "/Users/lokisinclair/Projects/nps:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - php
      - mariadb
  mailcatcher:
    container_name: mailcatcher
    image: yappabe/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - 1025:1025
      - 1080:1080
  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./php
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - "/Users/lokisinclair/Projects/nps:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"    # PHP
     - "5000:5000"    # ProcessTags.py
    links:
      - mariadb
      - mailcatcher
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_USER=homestead
      - DB_PASS=secret
  mariadb:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./database:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./mariadb:/tmp"
    command: mysqld --init-file="/tmp/init.sql"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead
      - MYSQL_USER=homestead
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

I've attempted to rewrite the nginx .conf several times, using various guides but it will always respond with `[XYZ] is not allowed here in...`- which isn't overly helpful. This conf works, but just can't access the php container. Can anyone shed some light, please?

**Update** 
I've since installed telnet on the web container and attempted to access port 9000, but its refused at command line too.

php dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0.0-fpm

LABEL maintainer="<REMOVED>"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    g++ \
    libc-client-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libkrb5-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssl-doc \
    libsasl2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    python3.4 \
    python-pip \
    libmysqlclient-dev \
    python-dev \
    procps \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    bz2 \
    iconv \
    mbstring \
    mysqli \
    pgsql \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_pgsql \
    soap \
    zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && yes '' | pecl install imagick && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap \
    && pecl install memcached && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb \
    && pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && apt-get autoremove -y --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -Rf /tmp/* \
    && pip install nltk \
    && pip install MySQL-python

# Grab python NLTK libs
RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all

# Set working directory to root of Insight
WORKDIR "/usr/share/nginx/html"

ADD init.sh /tmp/init.sh
CMD chmod +x /tmp/init.sh
CMD /bin/bash /tmp/init.sh

 # Expose network ports
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: `fastcgi_param DB_HOST mariadb:33061;` should be changed to `fastcgi_param DB_HOST mariadb:3306;`, because it is comunication between containers in their network.

Comment: Really? Even though I've mapped 33061 to 3306 in the yaml? I'm not sure that gets around the fact that port 9000 is refused on the php container though.

Comment: yes, `mariadb` container is available on port 3306 for other containers. maybe it is somehow related to your issue.

Comment: Changed the mariadb port in nginx conf, no change though.

Comment: It seems `php-fpm` doesn't work inside `php` container. Could you please provide the `Dockerfile` of `php` image?

Comment: But I'm able to run `php artisan`to migrate and seed - regardless, added. init.sh has the lines for artisan migrate and db:seed

Comment: your container is named `db`, while you refer to it with mariadb...

Comment: Thank you @Nickolay - You pointed me in the right direction. For some reason, artisan would only run under normal php. But web relied upon php-fpm, so I needed to start that as a process once artisan had completed. Cheers.